# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format:

Tags: ios

NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format:  I am planning to do a dynamic auto layout for a question and answer but I got this error after I do my nslayout constraint.

```
    UIScrollView *view = self.view;
        NSDictionary *viewDictionary = @{@"view":view,
                                         @"control":control  
        };
        NSArray *horizontalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:-0-[view]-0-“  options:0  metrics:nil
        views:viewDictionary];

        NSArray *verticalContraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:-[control]-[view]-"  options:0 metrics:nil
        views:viewDictionary];

        [self.view.superview addConstraints: verticalContraints];
        [self.view addSubview:control];
        [self.view.superview addConstraints:horizontalConstraints];
```

The error is:

> error *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format: 
>   Expected a view 
>   H:-0-[view]-0-

Comment: Post the code where you are creating the constraint as well as the entire error message you are getting.

Comment: To me it looks like your constraints are all wrong. I mean what are you trying to accomplish here? your vertical constraint looks like its trying to place control on top of the scroll view and your horizontal constraint is saying place them side by side. Idk i think that will cause a conflict.

Answer (score 3):

Add the control subview to the superview before adding the constraints. That way autolayout can make sense of the constraints being added.

The visual format language expects a '|' character to delimit the edges of the superview. Try this for the horizontal

```
|-[view]-|
```

and this for the vertical

```
V:|-[control]-[view]-|
```